# Chef - run install block based on variable condition

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, dsl, chef-recipe

Background: our systems are setup in a way that I will only be able to see the local chef log and will have no access to the Chef server console or any other sysadmin privileges. Hence I have a need to log locally if I want to see if or why something failed.

I can hear you asking " If you don't trust the pkg or Chef to install it correctly, then..." My answer is that while you are correct, I still want to be covered by the occasional anomaly.

My goal is to install a pkg, check to see that it installed correctly than go on to the next pkg.

On to the question:

I would like to set a variable that checks for the existence of a directory that was created by the first package using the following code:

```
   mycond = ::File.directory?('/opt/MyPkg/conf')
    Chef::Log.fatal("MyPkg package not installed ? conf dir is missing") unless mycond
```

the next stage in the recipee is to run the next install block checking to see if the variable has been set.

```
yum_package 'OtherPkg' do
  action :install
  only_if { mycond }
end
```

My question is since the `only_if` is failing, I was wondering if there was something wrong with the way I am setting the `mycond` variable ? perhapes {} braces are needed somewhere in the code ?

Total Chef newbie so please be specific with your answer.

Thanks !

Full code below:

```
yum_package 'MyPkg' do
      flush_cache [ :before ]
      action :install
    end

    mycond = ::File.directory?('/opt/MyPkg/conf')
    Chef::Log.fatal("MyPkg package not installed ? conf dir is missing") unless mycond

    yum_package 'OtherPkg' do
      action :install
      only_if { mycond }
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Chef's two-pass model. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for the full explanation for for this you just need to move the condition check in to the `only_if` block itself since that is delayed until converge time: `only_if { ::File.directory?('/opt/MyPkg/conf') }`.

Using the `fatal` log level is also probably not a good idea as this isn't actually a fatal error as written.

Comment: How can i get it to write to the local log as well?

Comment: I would probably use a log resource for that.

Answer (score 3):

Chef has an order of precidance that controls the flow of execution.

Code inside resource blocks (e.g. 'yum_package') will execute AFTER any loose code in your recipe.

The following lines are being executed FIRST, before your 'yum_package' blocks:

```
mycond = ::File.directory?('/opt/MyPkg/conf')
Chef::Log.fatal("MyPkg package not installed ? conf dir is missing") unless mycond
```

I believe you can nest resource blocks. You cold be able to combind all this code in a 'ruby_block' and it should execute in order as you'd expect.

Comment: and a variable set in a ruby block will be preserved/available in the next install block ?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any documentation on nested blocks but you were correct in identifying the root cause.